# svg-код для сайта

Tags: svg

Вопрос дилетантский, но очень хотелось бы разобраться. Существует разработка для сайта https://makitatrading.ru/catalog/category/178/ (при клике на деталь чертежа она подсвечивается и далее отправляется в корзину), понимаю, что это реализовано на базе SVG. Все детали отрисовываются в векторе, сохраняются в формате svg, получают код, который и вставляется на сайт. Как подсветка привязана к определенному месту чертежа? Что необходимо сделать, чтобы повторить этот функционал с любой другой картинкой. Где об этом почитать? 
Спасибо!

Comment: Всего лишь висит js-событие `onclick` на элементах `<path>`, которое отображает и скрывает их при клике, вот и всё

Comment: Причём в исходниках сайта английским по белому написано, что этот svg создан с помощью [Raphaël](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/). Там же в исходниках страницы лежит и код создания этого svg в открытом и читабельном виде

Comment: Мне почему-то даже не лень выдрать это из исходников https://jsfiddle.net/2c94zwa3/ (только имейте в виду, что этот код из сайта не принадлежит ни вам, ни мне, и просто так брать и использовать его нельзя)

Comment: andreymal, Спасибо за объяснение! Мне чисто в образоватеных целях.